# Avoid Unity error check for undefined #if code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a Unity (v2019.1.11) project where I have the following case of a class that is being included via a `git submodule` from another project where the namespace (`CustomNameSpace`) exists:

```cs
#if FLAG
using CustomNameSpace;

public class Foo
{

}
#endif
```

In my project at hand `CustomNameSpace` does not exist. Therefore I thought that unless I define `FLAG` in Unity's player settings, the file containing this code would be treated as if it was empty. However, even though `FLAG` is undefined, Unity is throwing an error for the missing namespace.

I would like to know how to correctly being able to avoid code files to be compiled or even checked by Unity.

**EDIT:** 
I already have checked that: 
- `FLAG` is not defined in the Unity player settings 
- `FLAG` is not defined in any code file in the solution 
- `FLAG` is not defined in `Assets\csc.rsp` as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html)

Comment: This is correct.  That flag is being set somewhere.

Comment: But where could that be? It's for sure not set by me at least. And I don't know any place to set it apart from the player settings. Do you know one?

Comment: I think there might a Unity mechanism that checks any code file without considering the ```#if```s

Comment: No, there is no such mechanism.  `FLAG` is being set somewhere.  https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html  Maybe you could search your entire project for "FLAG"?

Comment: ```FLAG``` is neither defined in any code file in the solution, nor in the Unity player settings. Is there somewhere else to search?

Comment: It won't be defined in a code file.  Include all `.csproj` and `.sln` files in your search.

Comment: It's probably colliding with something else. Try using a more "namespaced" alternative like `#if ZACH_FLAG`

Comment: My ```FLAG``` is called differently indeed, something that wouldn't be defined in any third party dll included

Answer (score 1):

This flag is being defined somewhere in your project, either inside the script or inside unity's project settings.

You need to find where it is being defined and remove the definition, so unity doesn't compile the code inside it.

1) It can be defined in your unity project settings window, to find it: Edit => Project Settings => Player tab, then find the text input field the one in the green box in this [image: screenshot], you'll probably find the FLAG symbol being defined there, remove it.

2) Or could be defined somewhere in your code, to find it: I will assume you're using visual studio as your IDE, press CTRL+ SHIFT + F and search your whole solution for this line of code `#define FLAG` this line is what defines your flag and making unity recognize the flag as being currently true, thus compiling the code inside it, it is the line you wanna remove.

Comment: Both suggestions negative

Comment: Don't search from within VS.  It will not search .csproj or .sln files.  Search using something that isn't an IDE, and include *everything*.  The flag is being set *somewhere*.  This is not disputable.  Expand your search if you can't find it.

Comment: @BenjaminZach Search also inside any dlls that came from the same source of the code you're trying to hide from unity.